# Sorry I'm late, the car wouldn't start this morning!

Tags: tenses, past-tense, will-would

This sentence is used in a Grammar book. I wonder why they used "wouldn't start"? Thanks so much!

Comment: The speaker is *blaming* the car for her tardiness, saying it *refused* (lacked the *will*) to start, even though she had asked it to (start). The phrase wouldn't nearly as well as an excuse if she were merely describing the situation factually.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> X won't/wouldn't Y

is often used to mean

> X refuses/refused to Y

Other examples:

> I am trying to talk to Jack, but he won't listen. (= he refuses to listen)
>
> I tried everything to open that can, but it just wouldn't give in.

Also, this construct implies certain effort. When you say

> My car wouldn't start.

you're implying that you kept trying for some time. There is no such implication in

> My car didn't start.

This is perhaps why *wouldn't start* is is better than *didn't start* when you're explaining to your boss why you're late.

Comment: Not my upvotes. Why can't the user say "My car hasn't started this morning"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I never said they can't. I just explained what won't/wouldn't means in this context. To answer your question: Because you're specifying a time in the past "this morning", the past simple would be much more natural, i.e. My car *didn't* start. But it's just a factual statement while *wouldn't* is more emotional

Comment: Now I need a place to hide away,
Oh, I believe in yesterday.

Why she
Had to go I don't know, she wouldn't say. 'Yesterday' The Beatles.

Comment: +1 but you avoided the present perfect bit. See Josh61's tip.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: How is Josh61's "tip" related to "the present perfect bit" which I have allegedly avoided? O_O

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան (thanks autocompletion): Josh put the emphasis on *Had* to go (past tense), because it happened yesterday. Also, the quotation has a *she wouldn't say* (refused to say). So the lyrics answer both questions of the user at once.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "hasn't" implies a level of automation - that you would expect your car to have started *of its own accord,* and you're late because it failed to do so. That's obviously a bit weird. "Wouldn't" implies instead that *attempts had been made to start the car, but have been unsuccessful*

Comment: @Kai *implies a level of automation* so does the expression, "the car didn't start this morning", but there's nothing wrong with it. I was only egging ArmenԾիրունյան to write a full answer, it needed just the finishing touches, it was already good. The OP has deleted all references to the past perfect, so my comment is "obsolete".

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Hasn't started" implies a failure to start over a period of time -- "My car hasn't started all week." "Didn't start" implies a failure to start at some particular time.

Comment: Technically, if your car "didn't start" this morning it could be because you never actually turned the key.  "Wouldn't start", while in effect blaming the car (and implying that it possesses volition), at least indicates that you (or someone) attempted to start it.

Comment: Also, the literal definition of "wouldn't" is "did not have the will to," which is pretty funny when you think of cars starting, but gets at the heart of why the wording is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is anthromorphic: merely continuous.   You absolutely can't say "My car didn't start this morning"; it clearly did, or you wouldn't be here to say so. What you can say is ""I tried the starter a dozen times, but none of them were successful," or more simply "It wouldn't start".

Comment: My car wasn't working this morning, so I took the bus. (Is that wrong?)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Not wrong, but a different shade of meaning. I would understand *It wasn't working this morning* to mean "I knew it wouldn't (I called the garage yesterday)". Whereas *it wouldn't start* implies 'I don't know why'.

Comment: Speaking as a resident to tropical southern Minnesota I can state without reservation that your appearance (late) at work does not provide evidence that your car eventually started.  You may have hitched a ride, you may have taken your wife's car, you may have taken the bus.  Or (not unlikely), the wrecker dropped you off at work as it was towing your car in for service.